# How to prove the map $f:A \to (A^{t})^{-1}$ is an inner automorphism on $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I notice that if $f$ is an inner automorphism, then we have $$\begin{align*}
f(A)=P^{-1}AP = (A^{t})^{-1}
\end{align*}$$ this makes to want to prove that $A$ and $(A^{t})^{-1}$ are always similar in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ .

Indeed, I proved the statement above by computing the Jordan form. But, I finally noticed $P$ may depend on $A$. However if $f$ is an inner automorphism, then we have $f(A)=(A^{t})^{-1}=P^{-1}AP$ where $P$ shoud not depend on $A$ .

That is, I think I have to prove that $\forall A \in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ , there exist a $P$ such that $$\begin{align*}
(A^{t})^{-1} = P^{-1}A P
\end{align*}$$ for all $A$. Then I think I don't know what I should do. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: There is indeed a simple matrix $P$ that satisfies this equation for *all* $A\in SL(2,\Bbb R)$. Write down concrete matrices, like $A=\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By observation and several trials, the matrix $$\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ -1 &0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$ perfectly solves the problem